# How to stop kubernetes from reporting to usage.projectcalico.org?

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I found that my kubernetes cluster was sending reports to usage.projectcalico.org, how can this be disabled and how exactly is it using usage.projectcalico.org?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Felix is the Calico component that sends usage information.

Felix can be [configured](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.7/reference/felix/configuration) to disable the usage ping.

Set the `FELIX_USAGEREPORTINGENABLED` environment variable can be to `"false"` (needs to be a string in yaml land!) in the `calico-node` DaemonSet

Set the `UsageReportingEnabled` field in the [FelixConfiguration](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.7/reference/calicoctl/resources/felixconfig) resource to `false`. This could be in etcd or in the Kubernetes API depending on what store you use. Both modifiable with `calicoctl`.

```
calicoctl patch felixConfiguration default \
  --patch='{"spec": {"UsageReportingEnabled": false}}'
```

If you happen to be using kubespray, modifying this setting is a little harder as these variables are not exposed to Ansible, other than by manually modifying [templates](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/a2cf6816ce328032d9ad457b7c2cdb23d9519b1b/roles/network_plugin/calico/templates/calico-node.yml.j2) or [yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/a2cf6816ce328032d9ad457b7c2cdb23d9519b1b/roles/network_plugin/calico/tasks/install.yml#L144-L162).

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code:

```
    # Disable Usage Reporting to usage.projectcalico.org
    # We want to avoid polluting analytics data with unit test noise
    curl_etcd("calico/v1/config/UsageReportingEnabled",
                   options=["-XPUT -d value=False"], ip=ip)
```

And here is the definition of `curl_etcd`

```
def curl_etcd(path, options=None, recursive=True, ip=None):
    """
    Perform a curl to etcd, returning JSON decoded response.
    :param path:  The key path to query
    :param options:  Additional options to include in the curl
    :param recursive:  Whether we want recursive query or not
    :return:  The JSON decoded response.
    """
    if options is None:
        options = []
    if ETCD_SCHEME == "https":
        # Etcd is running with SSL/TLS, require key/certificates
        rc = check_output(
            "curl --cacert %s --cert %s --key %s "
            "-sL https://%s:2379/v2/keys/%s?recursive=%s %s"
            % (ETCD_CA, ETCD_CERT, ETCD_KEY, ETCD_HOSTNAME_SSL,
               path, str(recursive).lower(), " ".join(options)),
            shell=True)
    else:
        rc = check_output(
            "curl -sL http://%s:2379/v2/keys/%s?recursive=%s %s"
            % (ip, path, str(recursive).lower(), " ".join(options)),
            shell=True)

    return json.loads(rc.strip())
```